# Ninject bbv EventBroker subscription error

Tags: events, ninject, publish-subscribe

I am attempting to use bbv.common.EventBroker with Ninject and am running into a few problems getting things wired up correctly.

I currently am using Ninject factories to create an item and then, since I subscribe to events, use the eventbroker to do the subscription. However when the register method is called I get an error that I can not find any information for at all. I am not even sure what the error means.

**Error:**

bbv.Common.EventBroker.Exceptions.RepeatedSubscriptionException occurred
  Message=Cannot add more than one subscription handler method of the same subscriber one topic: 'Method1'.
  Source=bbv.Common.EventBroker
  StackTrace:
       at bbv.Common.EventBroker.Internals.EventTopic.ThrowIfRepeatedSubscription(Object subscriber, String handlerMethodName)
       at bbv.Common.EventBroker.Internals.EventTopic.AddSubscription(Object subscriber, MethodInfo handlerMethod, IHandler handler, IList`1 subscriptionMatchers)
       at bbv.Common.EventBroker.Internals.EventInspector.HandleSubscriber(Object subscriber, Boolean register, MethodInfo methodInfo, EventSubscriptionAttribute attr, IEventTopicHost eventTopicHost)
       at bbv.Common.EventBroker.Internals.EventInspector.ProcessSubscriber(Object subscriber, Boolean register, IEventTopicHost eventTopicHost)
       at bbv.Common.EventBroker.EventBroker.Register(Object item)
  InnerException:

**Code:**

```
public const string Topic1 = "Topic1";
public const string Topic2 = "Topic2";
public const string Topic3 = "Topic3";
public const string Topic4 = "Topic4";

public ItemHelper(IItem item, IEventBroker eventBroker)
{
  _item = item;
  eventBroker.Register(this);
}

[EventSubscription(Topic1, typeof(bbv.Common.EventBroker.Handlers.Publisher))]
public void Method1(object sender, SomeArgs1 args)
{
  ...
}

[EventSubscription(Topic2, typeof(bbv.Common.EventBroker.Handlers.Publisher))]
public void Method2(object sender, SomeArgs2 args)
{
  ...
}

[EventSubscription(Topic3, typeof(bbv.Common.EventBroker.Handlers.Publisher))]
public void Method3(object sender, SomeArgs3 args)
{
  ...
}

[EventSubscription(Topic4, typeof(bbv.Common.EventBroker.Handlers.Publisher))]
public void Method4(object sender, SomeArgs4 args)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the class had an interface which had the [EventSubscription] attributes on its methods. The error message does make a lot more sense now that I know this.